# How can access property of .aspx in the user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an .aspx page in which I have a property. Now i create a user control and drop it on the page. Now how can i access that property in code behind of usercontrol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user control needs to access something on the parent page, then maybe this user control should have included it as its own property which could be set from the parent. Ideally user controls should be independent from any parent context or other user controls on the page, otherwise they really are not something reusable. They need to be self contained and configurable throughout their the properties they are exposing.

Comment: but what if I want to pass some value from user control to ites parent page for executing some function in the page. I think this should be very common scenerio and may be useable in some cases.

Comment: Yes, then you should expose this value as a property of the user control. The parent page has access to all public properties of all controls.

Comment: then how can I call any function of page in my user control.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. Please read my answer once again. If your control needs to call a function on the parent page this means that this user control is not reusable => you will never be able to put it on a page which doesn't have this function and thus making this user control useless. The correct way of communicating between the parent page and the user control should be done throughout public properties or events that the parent pages subscribes to.

Comment: If I check (this.Page is test.aspx) condition in user control then can I drop it on any page?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could do that but I won't recommend you. It's bad design.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to expose a public property in the UserControl and assign that property from the ASPX page:

By code:

```
var uc = this.myUserControl as MyCuserControlType;

uc.CustomUserControlProperty = this.MyPageProperty;
```

Declaratively

```
<uc:MyUserControlType1 runat="server= ID="myUserControl" CustomUserControlProperty="<%# this.MyPageProperty %>" />
```

Note: If you want to use declarative markup you would need to call `this.DataBind();` in code to force the binding

#### Edit 1

In case you want to do the opposite (pass a value from the control to the page in response to an event) you could declare your own custom event in the user control and fire it when needed it.

Example:

**User control code behind***

```
public event Action<string> MyCustomEvent = delegate{};

....
// somewhere in your code
this.MyCustomEvent("some vlaue to pass to the page");
```

**Page markup**

```
<uc:MyUserControl1 runat="server" onMyCustomEvent="handleCustomEvent" />
```

**Page code behind**

```
public void handleCustomEvent(string value)
{
    // here on the page handle the value passed from the user control
    this.myLabel.Text = value;
    // which prints: "some vlaue to pass to the page"
}
```

Comment: Actually I want to pass some value from user control to page for execution of some function on the page.

Comment: how can I call that handleCustomEvent function from Usercontrol code behind and pass parameter to it.

Comment: In your user control you call: `this.MyCustomEvent("some vlaue to pass to the page");` which is the event that you handle in your page